# FFmpeg: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, libraries, osx-el-capitan

I distributed the FFmpeg file built on Mac High Sierra.
When I tried to run it on OS X El Capitan, I got this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: /Applications/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I've googled it and found it can be fixed by updating `Mac OS`to Sierra or doing `brew update`.
But I want to distribute FFmpeg to my clients, I can not ask them to do the updates, do I have another workaround for this?